# Communicate two Android phones with NFC without Android Beam

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam, nfc-p2p

I am working with NFC in Android. I have done things with NFC tags and Android Beam, but I am wondering if is possible to communicate two Android phones with NFC without Android Beam.
I mean, I want to transfer some information, like a text or a URL using peer-to-peer in two Android phones, as if they were two NFC tags. I want to read and write this information in the other device, but the only way I have found to comunicate and trasfer data using P2P in Android is with Android Beam.
Is it possible?

PS. Sorry for mi english

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible - if you want to use NFC bearer, only the SNEP/NPP over LLCP is possible (i.e. peer2peer mode).

Petr

Comment: Minor addition: in Android 4.1 JB, the Bluetooth set-up via NFC (for automatic file transfer) uses LLCP, but not the standard SNEP. Tapping an Android NFC device with 4.0 ICS or earlier will result in an error message being shown.

Comment: Hi NFC guy - off topic question. Do you know really good SDK and NFC reader, that work in peer2peer mode? I have tried several open source solutions mentioned on stackoverflow, but none works really good... Also NFC reader/device compatibility question leads usually to answer "... but I have tried it with ACR122U and Nexus S or Galaxy Nexus...". I am looking for commercial solution:(

Comment: Which ones have you tried exactly? I am not aware of any existing commercial solution (but I did not extensively search for it either). I know there will be a commercial solution available for the [NXP CLRC663](http://www.nxp.com/demoboard/CLEV663B.html) eventually, but I don't know the exact timeframe.